# How to call a Controller from a PartialView in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a PartialView which I need to create a button on, and once a user clicks on this button, it must send a HTTPGET to a controller that receives the model. How do I call the HTTPGET action from the PartialView?

Any idea as to how to do this in MVC3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this solution work :

```
<form method="get" action="controllerName" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @html.partial("viewName")
 <input type="submit" value="Send" ... />
</form>
```

Comment: The Data just does not send. I have the fll. <form method="get" action="Projects" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <br />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Project Detail</legend>   
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
.......        </table>
    </fieldset>    
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
</form>
It says that action="Projects" Projects does not exist

Comment: well, do you set the parameter to your controller?
you should define a parameter with formCollection type and use it to get the data that submited from form

Comment: Sorry, Its a compile error,where my it says my 'controller' does not exist.

Comment: action name must be exist in your current controller,a function in your controller to do what you want

Comment: Hi, Sorry, i had placed the controller name and not the action name. Sorry, it works now. Thank YOU !! .One more thing, will the model from the PartialView also be passed back to this action method ? Thank you again Leon

Comment: Hi Leon, The call to the controller does not pass in the model from the PartialView. How can i pass the model from the PartialView to the HTTPGET in the controller ?

Comment: hi,sorry for late, formCollection right correctly,why you dont send data with this option? i think if you want send model you can use request.form["fieldName"] function or in parameter of your action use "ModelStateDictionary modelState, TempDataDictionary tempData" and get data from them

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply Leon.. i managed to get an answer on this one. Use of Jquery.. and it works :-)..thanks again for all yur help : <button id="btnEdit" type="button">Edit</button>                                                         <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
                    window.location = '@Url.RouteUrl(new { action  = "EditProject", projectCode = item.projectCode })';
                });
            });   
        </script>

Comment: your welcome, and jquery is good solution,tnx for share your solution

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you can achieve this.  The easiest way is to use an ajax request to send the data back to the controller using jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).  However I would not use a HTTP GET for this.  Although not enforced it is best to stick to using the HTTP verbs in the way that they were intended ie GET is for receiving data, POST is for sending data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

use this to create the form in your partial view,

```
@{using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Get, new { 
                                                   enctype = "multipart/form-data", 
                                                   id = "<id of the form>" }))
{

//body of your form

}
```

Here you can see that, type of the form method has been passed in to the Html.BeginForm method as "FormMethod.Get". If you want to sent the response to a Post method, uset "FormMethod.Post".

Comment: Thanks for the post, but how do i get the ID of the form ?

Comment: It's anything you like. Id is just used to uniquely identify a form, from a scripting language like Javascript.